# Coffeescript: Reference class method from instance method without hardcoding

Tags: coffeescript

Taking the following code as example:

```
class MyClass

  @staticMethod: -> hello_world()

  instanceMethod: -> MyClass.staticMethod()
```

Is there a way I could reference MyClass from inside `instanceMethod` without explicitly naming it? something like `self.staticMethod()`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) to get at the "class" just like in JavaScript:

```
instanceMethod: ->
    @constructor.staticMethod()
```

Demo (with added subclassing for good measure): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/zM3ND/